# Java how to return a part of a number?

Tags: java

I'm trying to return a part of a number, like so:

```
int foo = 123456789;

System.out.println( foo[0-3] ); //123
```

I'd also like to get a slice of the number for different indexes, from 2 to 5 for example. In Python, it is pretty straightforward but for some reason it's not so easy to do the same in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a number, not an array, so you can't do a slice on it. You need to convert it to `String` first and do a substring (= char array slice):

```
int foo = 123456789;
String slice = String.valueOf(num).substring(0, 3);
System.out.println(slice); // prints 123
```

If you need to use it as a number again, you need to convert it back to int:

```
int converted = Integer.parseInt(slice);
```

Comment: I see. There were a lot of results for array slicing but I thought there would be something for the single integer as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the int to String, substring it and parse it to an integer again:

```
int foo = 123456789;
String foorStr = Integer.toString(foo);
String fooSubstr = foo.substring(0, 3); //the last index is exclusive
int fooParted = Integer.parseInt(fooSubstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a method `parseInt` that lends itself to this.  It takes a String value, starting location, ending location, and a radix. You can make it a little easier as follows:

```
System.out.println(getSubNumber(123456789, 2,6));

public static int getSubNumber(int value, int start, int end) {
    return Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(value), start, end, 10);
}
```

prints

```
3456
```

or forego the method and just use `Integer.parseInt` directly.  There is an equivalent `Long.parseLong` for long types.

Answer (score 1):

int v=123456;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(v).substring(1,3));

Comment: Very useful. Thanks!